# Keep view id after rotation

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, screen-orientation, android-progressbar

I need to save the id after screen rotation. (Android 3.2+). Deatils:
In manifest:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

In Activity:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    initializeAnimation(true);
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        refreshView(true);
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        refreshView(false);
    }
}
```

refreshView method gets ListView's collection or GridView's collection from other class and put in ViewFlipper. The user can touch the element in List or Grid view and start downloading in AsyncTask and on the selected element displayed progress bar.

Model:

```
public List<ListView> getListViews(Context c) {
    listViews.clear();
    Iterator<List<Map<String, String>>> iter = arr.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        SimpleAdapter a = new SimpleAdapter(c, iter.next(), R.layout.vertical_list_view_item, new String[] { MONTH, IMAGE, DESCRIPTION}, new int[] { R.id.txtMonthV , R.id.imgV, R.id.txtDecriptionV});
        ListView lv = new ListView(c);
        lv.setDivider(null);
        lv.setDividerHeight(0);
        lv.setAdapter(a);
        listViews.add(lv);
    }
    return listViews;
}

public List<GridView> getGridViews(Context c){
    List<GridView> gridViews = new ArrayList<GridView>();
    Iterator<List<Map<String, String>>> iter = arr.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        SimpleAdapter a = new SimpleAdapter(c, iter.next(), R.layout.horizontal_list_view_item , new String[] { MONTH, IMAGE/*, DESCRIPTION*/}, new int[] { R.id.txtMonthH, R.id.imgH/*, R.id.txtDescriptionH*/ });
        GridView gv = new GridView(c);
        gv.setHorizontalSpacing(15);
        gv.setVerticalSpacing(15);
        gv.setNumColumns(6);
        gv.setAdapter(a);
        gridViews.add(gv);
    }

    return gridViews;       
}
```

Contoller:

```
public View currentView;

public View getCurrentPressedView(){
    return currentView;
}

public void setCurrentPressedView(View v){
    currentView = v;
}



@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    if (arg0 instanceof ListView) {
        /*....*/
        setCurrentPressedView(arg1);
        //Start download here
    } else if (arg0 instanceof GridView) {
        /*...*/
        setCurrentPressedView(arg1);
        //Start download here
    }
}
```

In async task:

```
View view;
ProgressBar proBar;
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        view = getCurrentPressedView();
        proBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progress);
        proBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
///.....
@Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        mProDialog.setProgress(values[0]);
        proBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
```

In vertical_list_view_item and horizontal_list_view_item progress bar has same ID.
But when screen was rotated, id change and I can not control Progress bar. Can somebody help me? Thx

Answer (score 0):

Did you used a static variable to store the id ?

Comment: No, id changes after screen rotation, because we get other grid views or list views collection.